# Basis of a polynomial ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Considering $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ as a direct sum $\bigoplus_{i,j=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{C} \cdot x^iy^j$, it can be viewed as an infinite dimensional vector space. In the same spirit, I am trying to calculate a C-linear basis for a polynomial quotient ring like $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^n-y+y^n)$. I know that it should be doable with the division algorithm but in this context it's not clear to me how it should be applied.

Comment: Hint: it is a bit easier when you think about $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ as $(\mathbb{C}[y])[x]$ (the round brackets are superfluous from a mathematical perspective, but try to clarify the 'think about as' part)

Comment: that could help me write  $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^n-y+y^n)$ as $\bigoplus_{i=0}^{n -1}x^i \cdot \mathbb{C}[y]$ so that $(1,\ldots,x^{n-1})$ would be a basis but is this all that can be done?

Comment: Sort-of... This way of writing shows that you only need to consider powers of $x$ up to $n-1$, but in order to get a basis over $\mathbb{C}$ you still have to 'break up' the $\mathbb{C}[y]$ part. But this works just as in your Original Post

Comment: Yes, $\oplus_{0 \leq i \leq n-1, 0 \leq j} \mathbb{C} \cdot x^i y^j  $, but I was expecting to find a finite basis. Was I wrong?

Comment: Of course I was.

Comment: But can I expect the dimension to be the same if I consider $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ as $(\mathbb{C}[x])[y]$ and try to find a $\mathbb{C}[x]$ base instead?

Comment: You have to be a bit careful when talking about $\mathbb{C}[x]$ bases because $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is not a field. The two $\mathbb{C}$-bases you get starting from $(\mathbb{C}[x])[y]$ and from $(\mathbb{C}[y])[x]$ have the same dimension: countable infinite.